Statistical factors: stability over time
I have an asset returns matrix of shape (n, t) with n assets and t days, n > t. I perform SVD decomposition of the matrix into c factors, getting a (c, t) shaped matrix of factor returns.
This process repeats with a sliding window of let's say 63 days, shifting one day at a time. Now the question is, are the factors from the previous window the same as from the current one?
To test this, I compute cosine distance between overlapping parts (62 days) of the subsequent factor return vectors. If the factors are the same, their returns will be the same. Here is the plot of those distances for the first factor.

In most cases, the distance is zero or close to zero, which is what we want.
Sometimes the distance is two, which means that the vectors are opposed. As far as I know, this comes from SVD sign flipping and is a minor nuissance.
The problem is with distances close to one, with vectors being nearly orthogonal. This means that the factor changed between windows. It's an entirely different factor now.
The question is how to ensure that the factors stay the same or close from one window to the next. Is there a popular, robust and simple way of dealing with the problem?

What is in the $x$ axis of this chart?

The X axis is time - days.


are the factors from the previous window the same as from the current one?

In general, no. They are probably better thought of as rotations and scalings (and minor other evolution) of each other. Each matrix you present to SVD is decomposed in isolation.  Assuming you use the same universe of securities, some of the characteristic portfolios (weightings across rows) are likely to be similar, and the interpretation of the similar portfolios is likely to be similar. Cosine similarity is a reasonable metric for this.

how to ensure that the factors stay the same or close from one window to the next.

You probably want the factor semantics to maintain continuity, but companies have birth and death processes. Commercial indices (and factor models) all have mechanisms ("rebalancing") to accommodate evolution of the component assets over time.
While not constraining the factors to be "the same or close", a paper of mine with my PhD advisor tracks the evolution of characteristic portfolios: Keane and Corso, "Maintaining prior distributions across evolving eigenspaces: An application to portfolio construction."

Is there a popular, robust and simple way of dealing with the problem?

Periodic rebalancing is the most generic task that addresses this "problem". Factor loadings and factor portfolios of well know commercial and academic products are typically re-estimated at some specified frequency.
